How should i correct my classification table in logistic regression?
The omnibus tests of model coefficients show that the model is significant. However, the classification table under Block 1 shows the same ratio of observed to predicted values as Block 0. Does this mean that my independent variables do not contribute to the model? my nagelkarke, cox & snell are very small as well but the variables in the equation shows significant results.
I wanted to know how to correct the classification table. May I use the SMOTE N?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to Cross Validated! What do you want to correct, and why is it currently incorrect?  Also, what does SMOTE have to do with anything? SMOTE is typically used in situations where one outcome category is much more prevalent than the other (“imbalance”), and most statisticians would argue that such situations almost never call for special handling like SMOTE. Perhaps refer to some of the links in my profile for more details.

i want to correct the confusion matrix. i am assuming i have an imbalanced dataset (the majority class represents 80% and the minority class is almost 20%).   I have used SMOTE N (all my variables are in binary), the confusion matrix gives better results now. Do you think I should keep it this way?

The class imbalance is a feature to embrace, not a bug to fix. That is, if a category is rare, it should be predicted to occur with a lower probability than a category that is common. Deceiving the model by artificially balancing the categories is, with rare exceptions, a poor statistical practice. Perhaps look at the class imbalance links in my profile to start down the rabbit hole.
